# How to simplify *numbers*

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Here is an example:

[image]

Obviously one could cancel $10^{12}$ from the numerator and denominator. I think Mathematica does not do it because this operation is not exact in floating point arithmetic (these are machine numbers). But I don't really care about that level of precision here. How can I force Mathematica to do the cancellation?

(I cannot do it by hand, because this expression is generated automatically inside a bunch of other functions in my code.)

Comment: I know there are other, possibly better duplicates of this question.  Please comment if you find one so that I can add it to the header.

Answer (score 3):

One more way is as follows.

```
expr = (1.2*10^12 + 1.5*10^13 x)/(1.3*10^12 + 1.32*10^13 y);
Rationalize[expr, 0.01] // Simplify
```

> $$ \frac{6 (25 x+2)}{132 y+13}$$

Comment: `Rationalize[expr, 0]` is arguably safer and it works in this case.

Answer (score 1):

This works in version 9:

```
Simplify @ Rationalize @ Factor @ (1.2*10^12 + 1.5*10^13 x)/(1.3*10^12 + 1.32*10^13 y)
```

> (6 (2 + 25 x))/(13 + 132 y)

it doesn't in version 11.

Comment: This does not work here... see https://imgur.com/a/mJPH9.

Comment: @becko, it works in version 9. Just confirmed that it doesn't in version 11.

Comment: Any idea why it does not work in v11? Who is the culprit, `Factor`, `Rationalize` or `Simplify`?

Comment: @becko, `Factor[expr]` gives the `expr`  back in v11, so it must be the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

You can try converting these to ints (as the [`FractionalPart`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FractionalPart.html) will be zero)

```
(1.2*^12 + 1.5*^13 x)/(1.3*^12 + 1.3210*^13 y) /. 
  r_Real?(FractionalPart[#] === 0. &) :> IntegerPart[r] // FullSimplify

(60 (2 + 25 x))/(130 + 1321 y)
```